# Facet by year, with overlapping data

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize places where I've been over the last few years.

See the code below: I want to facet g1 by year (g2). Do I need to add year-end / year-beginning points to the data frame, or am I missing something obvious?

I've tried setting `group = 1`, but I'm not entirely sure what it's attempting to do.

My vision is for the final output to look something like this:

[image: pic1]

Or alternatively, like this, with some tweaking with mapping the "status" column to `geom_line`

[image: pic2]

Also, please point out any bad habits / inefficient code.

```
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

travel <- structure(list(place = c("Brighton", "Madrid", "Home", "Berlin", 
                                   "Geneva", "Home", "New York & Canada", "Home", "Isle of Wight", 
                                   "Home", "Copenhagen", "Home"), day.out = c("2009-09-06", "2012-07-23", 
                                                                              "2012-07-27", "2012-11-21", "2012-11-23", "2012-11-26", "2013-04-04", 
                                                                              "2013-04-15", "2013-08-26", "2013-08-29", "2014-03-14", "2014-03-17"
                                   ), day.back = c("2012-07-22", "2012-07-26", "2012-11-20", "2012-11-22", 
                                                   "2012-11-25", "2013-04-03", "2013-04-14", "2013-08-25", "2013-08-28", 
                                                   "2014-03-13", "2014-03-16", "2014-03-30"), status = c("Live", 
                                                                                                         "Travel", "Live", "Travel", "Travel", "Live", "Travel", "Live", 
                                                                                                         "Travel", "Live", "Travel", "Live")), .Names = c("place", "day.out", 
                                                                                                                                                          "day.back", "status"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -12L))
travel$day.out <- as.Date(travel$day.out)
travel$day.back <- as.Date(travel$day.back)
travel$midpoint <- travel$day.out + floor((travel$day.back-travel$day.out)/2)
travel$day.out <- as.character(travel$day.out)
travel$day.back <- as.character(travel$day.back)
travel <- melt(travel, measure.vars = c("day.out", "day.back"))
travel <- travel[order(travel$value, decreasing = TRUE), ]
travel$status <- factor(travel$status)
travel$value <- as.Date(travel$value)
travel$label <- travel$place
travel$label[seq(2, dim(travel)[1], 2)] <- ""
travel$year <- as.numeric(format(travel$value, "%Y"))
pos <- c(-2.5, 2.5)
travel$vjust <- rep(pos, times = dim(travel)[1]/4 , each = 2)
rm(pos)

g1 <- ggplot(travel, aes(y = 0, colour = place)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = value, alpha = status), size = 8) +
  geom_text(aes(x = midpoint, label = label, vjust = vjust), size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%b")) +
  labs(list(title = "g1", y = "", x = "")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")

g2 <- ggplot(travel, aes(y = 0, colour = place)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = value, alpha = status), size = 8) +
  geom_text(aes(x = midpoint, label = label, vjust = vjust), size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%b")) +
  labs(list(title = "g2", y = "", x = "")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_grid(year ~ .)

g1
g2
```

#### UPDATE 1

I've (manually) added year-beginning / year-end points, which is not ideal (is there a programmatic way to do this?), which has brought a new problem. The dates are of class `Date`, so faceting by year half-works (see code). I've played with `space = "free_x", scales = "free-x"`, with no success. Also, the code to set the `vjust` value for `geom_text` to either 2.5 or 2.5 has gone out of whack, is there a better way to set this?

```
library("reshape2")
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

travel <- structure(list(place = c("Brighton", "Brighton", "Brighton", 
                           "Brighton", "Madrid", "Home", "Berlin", "Geneva", "Home", "Home", 
                           "New York & Canada", "Home", "Isle of Wight", "Home", "Home", 
                           "Copenhagen", "Home"), day.out = c("2009-09-06", "2010-01-01", 
                                                              "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2012-07-23", "2012-07-27", "2012-11-21", 
                                                              "2012-11-23", "2012-11-26", "2013-01-01", "2013-04-04", "2013-04-15", 
                                                              "2013-08-26", "2013-08-29", "2014-01-01", "2014-03-14", "2014-03-17"
                           ), day.back = c("2009-12-31", "2010-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2012-07-22", 
                                           "2012-07-26", "2012-11-20", "2012-11-22", "2012-11-25", "2012-12-31", 
                                           "2013-04-03", "2013-04-14", "2013-08-25", "2013-08-28", "2013-12-31", 
                                           "2014-03-13", "2014-03-16", "2014-03-30"), status = c("Live", 
                                                                                                 "Live", "Live", "Live", "Travel", "Live", "Travel", "Travel", 
                                                                                                 "Live", "Live", "Travel", "Live", "Travel", "Live", "Live", "Travel", 
                                                                                                 "Live")), .Names = c("place", "day.out", "day.back", "status"
                                                                                                 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
travel$day.out <- as.Date(travel$day.out)
travel$day.back <- as.Date(travel$day.back)
travel$midpoint <- travel$day.out + floor((travel$day.back-travel$day.out)/2)
travel$day.out <- as.character(travel$day.out)
travel$day.back <- as.character(travel$day.back)
travel <- melt(travel, measure.vars = c("day.out", "day.back"))
travel <- travel[order(travel$value, decreasing = TRUE), ]
travel$status <- factor(travel$status)
travel$value <- as.Date(travel$value)
travel$label <- travel$place
travel$label[seq(2, dim(travel)[1], 2)] <- ""
travel$year <- as.numeric(format(travel$value, "%Y"))
# pos <- c(-2.5, -2.5, 2.5, 2.5)
# travel$vjust <- rep(pos, times = dim(travel)[1]/4)
# rm(pos)

g1 <- ggplot(travel, aes(y = 0, colour = place)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = value, alpha = status), size = 8) +
  geom_text(aes(x = midpoint, label = label), size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%b")) +
  labs(list(title = "g1", y = "", x = "")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_grid(year ~ .)

g1
```

#### UPDATE 2

Hi all,

Haven't had any success with this problem, maybe I over-elaborated in the initial question?

I thought I saw that someone had replied suggesting something with `facet_wrap`, but the problem from UPDATE 1 (`Date` class) remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there actually!

The `value` and `midpoint` values are specifying the year that you also want to facet over. You need to remove the "year" information from these values if you want the facets to work properly. I simply changed the values to all be this year instead:

```
travel$value <- as.Date(format(travel$value, "%m-%d"), "%m-%d")
travel$midpoint <- as.Date(format(travel$midpoint, "%m-%d"), "%m-%d")
```

The only problem I see with your `vjust` values is that you are trying to replicate them 34/4=8.5 times each, which will round down to 8 and give you an error. You can instead dynamically set the number of replicates using `length.out`

```
travel$vjust <- rep(pos, length.out=nrow(travel))
```

So you can add the `vjust` back in to your code now:

```
g1 <- ggplot(travel, aes(y = 0, colour = place)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = value, alpha = status), size = 8) +
  geom_text(aes(x = midpoint, label = label, vjust=vjust), size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 month"), labels = date_format("%b")) +
  labs(list(title = "g1", y = "", x = "")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_grid(year ~ .)
```

[image: Corrected output]

Hope this helps!